# Parameter Pack Matching Rules with Multiple Packs

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a function which takes another function, using parameter packs and some standard matching rules. As an example:

```
template <typename... TListElems, typename... TVectorElems>
void goal(void (*fn)(std::list<TListElems>..., std::vector<TVectorElems>...));
```

In order to disambiguate `TListElems` and `TVectorElems`, I added some `std::tuple<T...>*` so a caller can be explicit:

```
template <typename... TListElems, typename... TVectorElems>
void foo(std::tuple<TListElems...>*,
         std::tuple<TVectorElems...>*,
         void (*)(std::list<TListElems>..., std::vector<TVectorElems>...))
{
    // blah blah blah
}

void bar(std::list<int>, std::list<unsigned>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>)
{
    // blah blah blah
}

int main()
{
    foo((std::tuple<int, unsigned>*) nullptr,
        (std::tuple<float, double>*) nullptr,
        &bar);
}
```

Clang happily compiles this in the way I would expect, while g++ (7.2.1) gives the compilation error:

```
matching.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
matching.cpp:20:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::tuple<int, unsigned int>*, std::tuple<float, double>*, void (*)(std::list<int>, std::list<unsigned int>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>))’
         &bar);
             ^
matching.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: template<class ... TListElems, class ... TVectorElems> void foo(std::tuple<_Tps ...>*, std::tuple<_Elements ...>*, void (*)(std::list<TListElems>..., std::vector<TVectorElems>...))
 void foo(std::tuple<TListElems...>*,
      ^~~
matching.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
matching.cpp:20:13: note:   mismatched types ‘std::vector<TVectorElems>’ and ‘std::list<int>’
         &bar);
             ^
```

In `main`, I would *expect* the call to `foo` to deduce `TListElems` as `<int, unsigned>` and `TVectorElems` as `<float, double>`, leading `fn` to be of type `void (*)(std::list<int>, std::list<unsigned>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>)` (the way things operate when there is only one pack or if I had manually written the overload).

§14.8.2.5/10 is the closest the Standard comes to explicitly preventing the `foo` example from working:

> [Note: A function parameter pack can only occur at the end of a parameter-declaration-list (8.3.5). -end note]

The `std::list<TListElems>...` bit of `fn` seems like it would violate this note, but that's not entirely clear.

The question is: Who is right? GCC, Clang, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think clang is right here.

In `void (*)(std::list<TListElems>..., std::vector<TVectorElems>...)`, `TListElems...` is [a non-deduced context](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.7), which makes `TVectorElems...` also [a non-deduced context](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#6). But both parameter packs *are* deducible from the two tuple pointer arguments, and it's expected to be able to just [use that deduction result](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#4.sentence-3) here too.

I filed [gcc bug 83542](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83542).

Comment: §17.9.2.5/6 provides the reason why Jarod42's solution works (specifically: "If a type is specified as `void f(typename A<T>​::​B, A<T>)`, the `T` in `A<T>​::​B` is non-deduced but the `T` in `A<T>` is deduced"), but it is ambiguous to me as to if Clang or GCC actually has the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

You may make happy both compilers with non deducible type:

```
template <typename T>
struct non_deducible {
    using type = T;  
};

template <typename T> using non_deducible_t = typename non_deducible<T>::type;


template <typename... TListElems, typename... TVectorElems>
void foo(std::tuple<TListElems...>*,
         std::tuple<TVectorElems...>*,
         void (*)(non_deducible_t<std::list<TListElems>>...,
                  non_deducible_t<std::vector<TVectorElems>>...))
{
    // blah blah blah
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa2b726e432b9912)

Comment: I'd just use `non_deducible_t` on the function pointer type itself.  So `non_deducible_t<void (std::list<TListElems>...,std::vector<TVectorElems>...)>*`